# Getting Button label name "null" when coming from the Background Delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In My app I run the Timer when button press,

I want to run the Timer in Backgroun when so that i use this methods,

```
  - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   FirstViewController *view = [[FirstViewController alloc]init]; 
    [view Startbtnpress];  //call the startbtnmethod
 }
```

Within Startbtnpress method,

```
     -(IBAction)Startbtnpress
{

     NSLog(@"start.titleLabe:%@",start.titleLabel.text);

    if([start.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"START"])
 {
     myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(ShowActicity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
  else if([start.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"STOP"]
 {
   [myticker invalidate];

 }
}
```

When First Time call the start button method in  NSLog(@"start.titleLabe:%@",start.titleLabel.text);
I get the "START"

When i came through

```
     - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

In   NSLog(@"start.titleLabe:%@",start.titleLabel.text);
I get the Null value?

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try calling
`[view Startbtnpress];`
in viewDidLoad instead as the view might not be laoded at the time(esp. if loading from .xib file)

Comment: This is the issue. It's returning null because it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: I try to call [view Startbtnpress] method within viewdidload & within - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   FirstViewController *view = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];      [view viewDidLoad];
 }  But,still getting null...